# Is it possible to skip or ignore a attribute while using Streaming API of Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

[This](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ELSEPmFW) is my JSON source. Can we skip the `retweeted_status` token and move to the next `contributors` token (not the one inside the `retweeted_status` token).

Currently the following code goes into the `retweeted_status` object and parsing each one of them:

```
jp = jsonF.createJsonParser(strLine);
if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        throw new IOException("Expected data to start with an Object");
    }
    TwitterEntry result = new TwitterEntry();
    // Iterate over object fields:
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
        // Let's move to value
        jp.nextToken();
        if (fieldName.equals("id")) {
            result.setId(jp.getLongValue());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("text")) {
            result.setText(jp.getText());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("fromUserId")) {
            result.setFromUserId(jp.getIntValue());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("toUserId")) {
            result.setToUserId(jp.getIntValue());
        } else if (fieldName.equals("languageCode")) {
            result.setLanguageCode(jp.getText());
        } else { // ignore, or signal error?
            //Ignoring unrecognized fields
            //throw new IOException("Unrecognized field '"+fieldName+"'");
        }
    }
    jp.close();
```

Comment: Why you do not want to create Java POJO classes and deserialize your JSON to these classes? Why are you doing it manually?

Comment: I read from the Jackson docs that this method is the fastest one. I will be reading about 2K files(with each file having about 500 JSON results) per day.

Comment: But you want to read only 5 properties. You can define only these properties in POJO classes which you really want to use in app. It should be fast as well.

Comment: No this is a part of the API that I am reading. An example of the entire output is here - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CV6WNKtq

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use jp.skipChildren() in your else statement.

ie

```
...
else {
   jp.nextToken();  // go to value token
   jp.skipChildren();  // skip if object or array
}
...
```